# cypher vs neo4j-sh : why do we have both?

Tags: neo4j

I understand HOW the 2 differ:

- neo4j-sh (not it's real name I'm guessing) works with a file-system-like abstraction
- cypher is meant to be more of a SQL-like approach

But WHY do we have both?

I actually really like the ability to manipulate a data structure as a file system (like FUSE does with things like procfs) and would be happy to write all my important scripts in it.

But is it discouraged? The last thing I want to do is rely on a technology that will be unsupported or deprecated in the future.

Comment: There's also Gremlin, as well as the native Java API. And there's even a REST traversal API.

Comment: True, but I'm looking for a rapid, compact way to achieve it. I Wouldn't use JDBC groovy instead of a .sql file (or is this analogy inconsistent?).

Comment: Just mentioning that there are more than 2 options. neo4j-sh is one that many people haven't even heard of. Usually people like to debate: "Gremlin vs Cypher" or "native vs Cypher".

Comment: Okay, point taken. Thanks Wes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the neo4j-shell is intended for use in an application, the intended use case is rather during development and debugging. Note that it also supports Cypher queries. I'd say go with Cypher wherever possible.

The neo4j-shell has been around since way before Cypher was invented, so that's why we currently have both.

Comment: Also for operations. And the shell is a convenient way of executing cypher which works both in the command-line and the Neo4j-Server Web-UI. The Neo4j-Shell is also supporting importing and exporting data from Neo4j. Cypher is just one of the languages and APIs that it supports.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. I will avoid relying on the FUSE-like approach to DML and spend time learning Cypher even though it needs a bit more effort!